# Create new variable using loop

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to create two new variables in R using a loop.

Basically, what I would like to have is:

```
exp_1 = (edad - esc - 6)^1
exp_2 = (edad - esc - 6)^2
```

I've tried this, but the problem is that I get only the "exp_i".

```
for (i in 1:2){
  exp_i = (edad - esc - 6)^i
}
```

I understand that the use of "paste" and "assign" might help, but I don't get how to do it.

Comment: Hi Isidora! Welcome to StackOverflow. What are `edad` and `esc` in this context?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```r
for (i in 1:2){
  assign(paste0("exp_", i), (edad - esc - 6)^i, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Note: I think this is generally considered bad practice. It would probably be better to save them in a vector or list that you can call by index.

```r
exp_i <- c()

for (i in 1:2){
  exp_i[i] <- (edad - esc - 6)^i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that you can use the paste and assign functions in R to dynamically create and assign variable names within a loop.

```
for (i in 1:2) {
var_name <- paste("exp_", i, sep = "")

assign(var_name, (edad - esc - 6)^i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refrain from POLLUTING The global environment. It is advisable to use a container to store your values, eg a vector/list etc. Its easier to work with containers rather than having thousand of variables floating in the global environment.

In your example above:

If `edad` and `esc` are both vectors of length one, you could do:

```
result <- (edad - esc - 6)^(1:2)
names(result) <- paste0("exp_", 1:2)
```

`result` is a vector storing all your values. you can then extract the values you want:

```
result['exp_1']
```

If `edad` or `esc` are vectors of length > 1 then you do:

```
results <- outer(edad - esc - 6, 1:2, "^")
colnames(results) <- paste0("exp_", 1:2)
```

Now `results` is a matrix/array, that stores all the values you need. You can then extract the specific columns using:

```
results[, 'exp_1']
```

If at all you are still sure you need the variables, then you can spit the container values onto the global environment by using `list2env` function or the `attach` function

ie: If you have the vector `result`:

```
 attach(as.list(result)) # places the variables in the search path
```

or

```
 list2env(as.list(result), .GlobalEnv) #places the variables in the global environment
```

if you have the matrix `results`:

```
 list2env(data.frame(results), .GlobalEnv)
```

In each of the cases above, you can then refer to the variables with the common names.

```
 exp_1
```